# layout.getchildat() function does not work after update layout

Tags: android, layout, updates, children

I have a code like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent returnIntent) 
{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, returnIntent);

        RelativeLayout layout2=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RltLayout);
        Bundle extrasBundle = returnIntent.getExtras();

            String temp = extrasBundle.getString("FollowList");
            final int restSize;
            if(temp != null) {

                for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
                {
                    Button Bt=(Button) layout2.getChildAt(i) ;
                    CharSequence St= Bt.getText();
                    orders[i]=IndexOfLabel((String) St);
                }
                List<String> restList = Arrays.asList(temp.split(","));

                }
}
```

for the firs time, layout.getchildat() works perfect. when I change the layout and views, I get the previous results and the function does not work.
what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by `previous results and the function does not work.`? 
Can you explain it more?

Comment: for example, when I run this code for the first time there are 3 children in layout and the result is about these children and there texts. after it, I add 2 more children in layout and run this code again. the result is the same(just 3 children instead of 5 children)

Comment: Can you post little  more code?

Comment: if ( layout.getchildat (i) instanceof Button ) {  get text   }

Comment: Dear Kunu, I changed the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. actually it was my fault because before rearange the views I did not remove the old views. by adding the following code and remove all views and reconstruction the layout, I solved my problem.

```
if(layout2.getChildCount() > 0) 
                        layout2.removeAllViews();
```